# HTML5 Audio not working for Android

Tags: android, audio, html5, mp3

I am creating a page with an embedded audio player that works on all systems I have tested, except on Android. The players do appear on the page, but you cannot start them playing.

I've tried both the `<audio>` tag and [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), checked whether the device does normally play mp3 files with [HTML5 Audio Formats Test](http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/) (which it does), and downloaded that same test to my server and checked whether it worked there (which it doesn't). And I cannot find anything helpful in the log files.

Any ideas what I could do?

edit: I have since tried the same with Apache on the same server and with Nginx on another server with the same results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @alexus I do not get what you want to say. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that the page was protected with a password.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the files on my nginx server and all of them except flac work on android 4.4 with the default Browser and Firefox.

This is the tag I used:

```
<audio preload="auto" controls="">
   <source src="Test/Audio/mp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Maybe you have not set your mime types in the nginx configuration correctly.
You will need:

```
types {
  audio/mpeg                          mp3;
  audio/ogg                           oga ogg opus;
  audio/webm                          weba;
  audio/vnd.wave                      wav;
}
```

This can be done by importing mime.types in the server block and adding missing types.

If this did not help please write which browser/version you use ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, that was not the problem. All (needed) types were already set.